# Factorial recursion with a pass by reference function call?

Tags: c, recursion, parameters, factorial

I want to create a recursive Factorial using the Pass By Reference method.

```
int recursiveFactorialByValue(int x){

if (x==0||x==1) return 1;
else if (x<=0) return -1;
else return x * recursiveFactorialByValue(x-1);
}

void recursiveFactorialByReference(int *x){

int minusOne = *x - 1;
int *ptr = &minusOne;
if (*x==0||*x==1) *x = 1;
else if (*x <= 0) *x = -1;
else *x * recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr); //this is where the error occurs
}



int main(){

int x, *ptr=&x, **pptr=&ptr, y;

printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d",*&x);
y = x;

printf("%i! = %i\n",y,recursiveFactorialByValue(x));


recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr);
printf("%i! = %i\n", y, x);
return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
In function 'recursiveFactorialByReference':
14:7: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
else recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr) * *x;
```

I've tried different function calls like:

else *x = *x * recursiveFactorialByReference(*x-1);

else *x = *x * recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr);

and none of these work, I can't find the problem please help.

Comment: `recursiveFactorialByReference` does not return anything, so `*x * recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr);` does not make any sense. Also C does not support pass by reference, you are passing a pointer as parameter (by value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*x * recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr)
```

This multiplies the value pointed to by `x` (which is an `int`) with the return value of `recursiveFactorialByReference` (which is `void`), which makes no sense. Think about what your recursive function does: you pass it a pointer to an int and it *replaces* that int with its factorial. So your recursive part should look like this:

```
else
{
    recursiveFactorialByReference(ptr);
    *x *= *ptr;
}
```

Note that you still have to assign to `*x`. Multiplying it on its own just throws away the value.

Also you have an extra `*` in your scanf call. It should be

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Also these technically aren't "references" (that's a concept from C++). Both of your functions are passing values, the latter just happens to be passing the *values* of *pointers*.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I get it now! I was using "scanf("%d",*pptr);" at first and forgot to remove the * before replacing it with &x. Thanks so much again!